# Change visibility buttons in RepositoryItemButtonEdit by click

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have gridView with 3 columns. One column has repositoryItempictureEdit with 4 EditorButtons

```
this.repActionsBtn.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] {
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton()});
```

And i have a buttonClick event handler

```
private void repActionsBtn_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonEdit editor = sender as ButtonEdit;

            if (editor != null)
            {
                object obj = this.mainView.GetFocusedRow();
                int id = GetValueFromAnonymousType<int>(obj, "ID");

                //undo
                if (e.Button == editor.Properties.Buttons[0])
                {
                    _ignoredIds.Remove(id);
                }
                //delete
                else if (e.Button == editor.Properties.Buttons[1])
                {
                    //HERE i want change visibility buttons
                    e.Button.Visibility = false;
                    _ignoredIds.Add(id);

                }
                //edit
                else if (e.Button == editor.Properties.Buttons[2])
                {
                    _storedIds.Clear();
                    _storedIds.Add(id);
                    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry;
                }
                //save
                else if (e.Button == editor.Properties.Buttons[3])
                {
                    //save
                    _storedIds.Remove(id);
                }
                mainView.RefreshRow(this.mainView.FocusedRowHandle);
            }
        }
```

But fires redraw and i get default repositoryItemButtonEdit with buttons is visible.
How i can change visibility(or property Enabled) of EditorButtons by user actions. (For each row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devexpress support give me a solution. [Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q569430) you can find the solution and download test project.

Comment: but, it's solution is working for me. Have you downloaded and started their test project with solution?

Comment: What I am trying to do is when RepositoryItem is pressed, it should change from enable to disable. And vice versa. I mean toggling button using RepositoryItemButtonEdit.